# Angular 12 - How to digest Spring boot 2.5.1 JPA @query response consisting of multiple tables to show on Angular Form

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular12

I have created a JPA @ Query that has the primary source table, includes the inventory table multiple records via a join, and I also return person 1 and person 2 in the Response JASON Object return.  What do I need to do on the Angular side to format the response and refer to the different data elements coming back on the form?   For example - source.id source.desc and same page person.name, person.phone, inventory data.   I can't find any good examples on how to achieve this correctly.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using database entities on the frontend directly is a bad practice. Instead create DTOs (data transfer objects) to hold the data you need to get on the frontend, structured as you see fit for ease of handling. The mapping between entities and DTOs can be done (semi-)automatically, say, via [MapStruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct)

Comment: Thank you for your advice and MapStruct info.  Can you point me to a good Angular 12 with bootstrap against java spring-boot example or documentation on how to reference and set it up on the Angular side of things?